# Parse and return components of a date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a series of dates formatted similar to 2014-12-31 (year, month, day) loading into a webpage.

I'd like to use Javascript to reformat the date to appear as December 31, 2014 (month, day, year).

Is it possible to do this without splitting the string and reformatting; in other words, is it possible to only use Javascripts date() function?

For example, if I try:

```
d = new Date.parse('2014-12-31')
```

Is there a way to return only the year, month or day?

I tried d.getYear(), but that threw a "function not found" error.

Comment: `Date.parse` returns a timestamp, not a date object (at least on firefox). And you must not add `new` before `Date.parse`, `new` is for creating object, here you are calling a static method. If you want a `Date` object, you simply do `new Date('2014-12-31')`.

Comment: If you're able to use js libraries, I'd suggest using Moment.js. There are a ton of utility methods to both display and parse dates. http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use momentjs.com?  it's far more powerful than the default.

```
var yourInput = "2014-12-31";
var moment = require("moment");
var d = moment(yourInput);
var iYear = d.year();
var iMonth = d.month();
var iDay = d.day();
```

Comment: Though I would have liked a built-in Javascript solution, this is definitely the easiest way because I'm getting different results across browsers and I don't want to have a whole bunch of case scenarios. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but what I am showing is not very pretty, so I agree that using the well-established moment.js is a better idea. If you *must not* use libraries...

You have to be careful if the user is behind GMT, because creating a new Date (without a time in hours) will then be set to the previous day. `getTimezoneOffset()` is used to correct the desired date to midnight.

Also, you have to define an array of months to be displayed. By default, getting a month returns an integer from 0 to 11. (Jan = 0)

```js
     function myDateFormat(ymd) {
         var rawDate = new Date(ymd);
         var midnight = new Date(rawDate.getTime() +
                                 rawDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
         var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
                       "May", "June", "July", "August",
                       "September", "October", "November", "December"]

         return months[midnight.getMonth()] + " " +
                midnight.getDate() + ", " + midnight.getFullYear();
     }

     // test function
     function display(x) {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += x + "\n";
     }

     display("2015-02-15 is " + myDateFormat("2015-02-15"));
     display("2014-12-31 is " + myDateFormat("2014-12-31"));
     display("2015-10-10 is " + myDateFormat("2015-10-10"));
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `var d = new Date('2014-12-31');`

`Date.parse` returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, not a Date object.

Comment: That returns a NaN error. If I remove the "new", then I that returns the date. But d.getYear() still comes back as not a function.

Comment: In my node console, [it works perfectly](http://i.imgur.com/oy16tWm.png). With regards to your edit, getYear() [was deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear).

Comment: Well this is weird. I tried it on Chrome and Firefox and can't get your example to work: http://imgur.com/cM35t4U

Comment: You need the `new` keyword. I just confirmed my code works in the Firefox and Safari console.

Comment: Oy vey... I'm getting inconsistent results. If I run d.getFullYear() on Firefox, then it returns 2014. But if I run the same on Chrome, it return 2013. Also, d.getYear() returns 113 on Chrome.

Comment: Chrome 45 yields a correct `d.getFullYear()` for me. Additionally, `d.getYear()` returns 114.